# cc1: error: bad value (armv8-a) for -march= switch

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, u-boot

I am compiling u-boot for raspberry pi 3 as the steps mentioned on this link

http://www.embeddedforu.com/embedded-linux/raspberry-pi/how-to-compile-mainline-u-boot-for-raspberry-pi/

and i get this error:

> cc1: warning: unknow register name: x18
>
> lib/asm-offsets.c:1:0: error: bad value (armv8-a) for -march=switch

can anyone help me?

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: You mention a page of instructions, but exactly what did you do?  What's your host?  What toolchain are you using?

Comment: i tried the complilation as said in the link as if i don't have buildroot. So i download arm-linux-gnueabi- and exported that to CROSS_COMPILE then downloaded the u-boot version 2016.09, made the rpi_3_defcofing and ran make all. at this time im just trying to make things as the teacher says because he will explain after we have it working

Comment: Did you forget the `export ARCH=arm` command?

Answer (score 1):

What's the version of gcc, do you want to build `rpi_3_defconfig`(arm64) or `rpi_3_32b_defconfig`?

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
```

Use linaro toolchain 4.9, with following environment, pass build `rpi_3_defconfig`:

```
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2017.01/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz

CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-

ARCH=arm64
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are exporting and compiling with the same user (do not use sudo). For instance, the next commands will fail:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
make rpi_4_defconfig
sudo make
```

In that case the make command would ignore that you have exported your CROSS_COMPILE variable and try to compile U-Boot with your default local compiler.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using CLion to import aosp native.
Enter the root directory of AOSP

```
cd AOSPROOT/out/development/ide/clion
create CMakeLists.txt
# CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(custom)
add_subdirectory(art/libdexfile/libdexfile-arm64-android)
......
# add 
set(ANDROID_ROOT AOSPROOT)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${ANDROID_ROOT}/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r416183b1/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${ANDROID_ROOT}/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r416183b1/bin/clang++")
# end
```

Answer (score -1):

This Error because you use native toolchain not cross toolchain for rpi.

Here is the error message before specifying cross toolchan
[image]
after I specify the rpi toolchain everything works fine

[image]

so try this

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=path-to-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Comment: Your answer seems not to match the question: In the question register x18 was mentioned. This register does not exist on ARMv7.